# Need an help for css

Tags: css

I'm trying to make this animation:

http://codepen.io/suez/pen/ZGWbmE

```
    *, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.heart-loader {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -90px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: visible;
}
.heart-loader__group {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 90px;
      -ms-transform-origin: 0 90px;
          transform-origin: 0 90px;
  -webkit-animation: group-anim 7s 1s infinite;
          animation: group-anim 7s 1s infinite;
}
.heart-loader__square {
  stroke: #B8B8B8;
  stroke-dasharray: 240, 240;
  stroke-dashoffset: 240;
  -webkit-animation: square-anim 7s 1s infinite;
          animation: square-anim 7s 1s infinite;
}
.heart-loader__circle {
  stroke: #B8B8B8;
  stroke-dasharray: 188.522, 188.522;
  stroke-dashoffset: 188.522;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 60px 30px;
      -ms-transform-origin: 60px 30px;
          transform-origin: 60px 30px;
}
.heart-loader__circle.m--left {
  -webkit-animation: left-circle-anim 7s 1s infinite;
          animation: left-circle-anim 7s 1s infinite;
}
.heart-loader__circle.m--right {
  -webkit-animation: right-circle-anim 7s 1s infinite;
          animation: right-circle-anim 7s 1s infinite;
}
.heart-loader__heartPath {
  stroke: #E21737;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-dasharray: 308.522, 308.522;
  stroke-dashoffset: 308.522;
  -webkit-animation: heart-anim 7s 1s infinite;
          animation: heart-anim 7s 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes square-anim {
  12% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  43% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  85% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes square-anim {
  12% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  43% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  85% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes left-circle-anim {
  12% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 188.522;
  }
  31% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
  41% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
            transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  43% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
            transform: translateY(-30px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  85% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
            transform: translateY(-30px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
            transform: translateY(-30px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes left-circle-anim {
  12% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 188.522;
  }
  31% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
  41% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
            transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  43% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
            transform: translateY(-30px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  85% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
            transform: translateY(-30px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
            transform: translateY(-30px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes right-circle-anim {
  12% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 188.522;
  }
  31% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
  }
  41% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
            transform: translateX(30px);
  }
  43% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
            transform: translateX(30px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  85% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
            transform: translateX(30px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
            transform: translateX(30px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes right-circle-anim {
  12% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 188.522;
  }
  31% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
  }
  41% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
            transform: translateX(30px);
  }
  43% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
            transform: translateX(30px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  85% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
            transform: translateX(30px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
            transform: translateX(30px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes group-anim {
  43% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
            transform: rotate(0);
  }
  54% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  97% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes group-anim {
  43% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
            transform: rotate(0);
  }
  54% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  97% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes heart-anim {
  55% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 308.522;
    fill: transparent;
  }
  70% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: transparent;
  }
  87% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: #E21737;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: #E21737;
  }
}
@keyframes heart-anim {
  55% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 308.522;
    fill: transparent;
  }
  70% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: transparent;
  }
  87% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: #E21737;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: #E21737;
  }
}
.other {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}
.other__link {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}
```

happen only a time, and after, stops without reset.

I tried to use the `animation-fill-mode: forwards` but it dont work.

Sorry for my bad english and thanks all for the anwers!

I fixed that using `animation-fill-mode` as the last command for every object

Thanks anyways for your no help...

Comment: if the code is too long then only include the code in question. It shouldn't all be in question. You could also include things you've tried. Adding code helps put into perspective what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Done, now can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that using animation-fill-mode as the last command for every object